# Query Posts to display all posts with category "custom field value"

Tags: customization, query

I'm trying to figure out how to query posts on a custom post type, using a custom field.

Goal:
On my "artists" single page, I want to display a list of news/album releases for that artist only. Those posts will also show up on the main page.

Concept:
Use a category for each artist on the posts; use a custom field "news_category_slug" on each artist page to link them.  I then want to query posts and display all posts in the category that match the custom value "news_category_slug".

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way; I don't have much PHP knowledge so I'm having trouble figuring out if this is a bad approach or if I just don't understand how to nest a variable inside the query! Help!

Comment: why not use a single artist taxonomy for both? an artist post has its own artist term, and their news posts have that same term to connect them to the artist.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating artists as categories then their single page template will be category.php , in category.php add the following code :-

$category_id = get_cat_id( single_cat_title("",false) ); 
$cat_name = get_cat_name($category_id); 
$new=query_posts('post_type=news_album&cat='.$category_id.'&post_status=publish&orderby=ID&order=DESC&posts_per_page=-1');
if( have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
echo get_the_title($post->ID);
echo get_the_content($post->ID);

endwhile; else: echo "No posts added for this category!"; endif; wp_reset_query();

Answer (score 0):

if you use CPT then you should something like this:

```
<?php 
            query_posts(array( 
                'post_type' => 'artists',
                'showposts' => 10,
                'tax_query' => array(
                           array (
                             'taxonomy' => 'category_custom_post_type', // <= Name of the taxonomy created type category for the CPT
                             'field' => 'slug',
                             'terms' => 'news_category_slug', // <= Slug taxonomy
                          )
            ),
            ) );  
        ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        <?php endwhile;  
    // reset the orignal query we should use this to reset wp_query  
    wp_reset_query(); ?>
```